# ElasticSearchRepository null query does not work

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

Spring data elastic search repository doesn't work as expexcted. For the method below, it gives the following exception.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal
>   criteria found 'IS_NULL (0): [IsNull, Null]'.

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Customer, Long> {

   List<Customer> findByFirstNameIsNull();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like below in the repository:

```
Page<Customer> findByFirstName(String firstName, Pageable pageable);
```

And calling it with

```
findByFirstName(null, PageRequest.of(0,100));
```

Will give you the first 100 results that have null values in their first names.